# Stackoverflow calling metaClass method on Map

Tags: java, groovy, stack-overflow

This piece of code is causing a stackOverflow exception:

```
ISerializer serializer = buildSerializer(TestDataProvider.getAuthor());
ASObject result = (ASObject) serializer.serialize();
assert result.isNotLazyProxy
```

The StackOverflow is being thrown on this line: `assert result.isNotLazyProxy`.  Note, the `isNotLazyProxy` method never actually gets called.

`isNotLazyProxy` is a extension method *(what are these called in groovy?)* defined as follows:

```
/**
 * Asserts that this ASObject is not a lazy loaded proxy,
 * ie - that all of it's properties' values have been included
 */
ASObject.metaClass.isNotLazyProxy = { ->
    assert delegate[HibernateProxyConstants.PROXYINITIALIZED] == true
    return true;
}
```

However, setting a breakpoint on the first line of that closure shows that it never gets called.

Instead, there's a StackOverflow thrown:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.lang.String.getChars(String.java:855)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:391)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:224)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.<init>(StringBuffer.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.formatMap(InvokerHelper.java:557)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.format(InvokerHelper.java:530)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.formatList(InvokerHelper.java:602)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.format(InvokerHelper.java:527)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.formatMap(InvokerHelper.java:575)
```

*snip*

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but `ASObject` is a subclass of a `Map`, and it's contents may have properties that refer to other keys within itself.

I would've have thought it was relevant, except the StackOverflow appears to indicate that groovy is traversing the members of the map.

What's going on?  Why is this stackoverflow occurring?

Comment: Which line is causing the exception, is it the assert?

Comment: @tim_yates Whoops! Updated the question to clarify, but it's the  `assert result.isNotLazyProxy` that causes the exception.

Answer (score 1):

`assert result.isNotLazyProxy` is probably not doing what you want to do.

In groovy `map.somehing` is translated to `map.get(something)`. See http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1035-Maps :

> assert map2.class == null
>   //field syntax always refers to value of key, even if it doesn't exist
>   //use getClass() instead of class for maps...
>   assert map2.getClass() == LinkedHashMap //the kind of Map being used

So use `assert result.isNotLazyProxy()`.

Of course `result.isNotLazyProxy` should return null in your case, and the `assert result.isNotLazyProxy` assertion should fail. When this assertion fails groovy will display an assertion error, and the map. In your case formatting the map fails for some reason.

Reason it fails:

It is a [known bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3250), see [example](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/441001). As I see, it has nothing to do with [ASObject](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.adobe.blazeds/blazeds-core/3.0.0.544/flex/messaging/io/amf/ASObject.java), as it uses no lists.

Comment: i'd say the map has a list that has the map, thus creating a loop

Comment: jpertino thanks, you are right, I've updated the answer. It is known bug in groovy.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it looks like something else is causing the endless recursion...

Does `ASObject` have any other metaClass methods?  Especially those overriding the `getAt( key )` method of `Map`

I came up with this quick test script, and it seems to work fine as I'd expect (and I *think* it does the same as what you say you're doing)

```
class ASObject {
  @Delegate Map map = [ 'PROXYINITIALIZED' : true ]
}

ASObject.metaClass.isNotLazyProxy = { ->
    assert delegate[ 'PROXYINITIALIZED' ] == true
    return true
}

assert new ASObject().isNotLazyProxy()
```